# Uniqueness validation performance

Tags: performance, validation, core-data

When performing uniqueness validation in Core Data in the usual way (via `NSManagedObject validate…`), complexity is O=(n²) because every entity is going to compare itself to every other entity of its type.

Is there a straightforward way to get linear performance for Core Data uniqueness validations? Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a class-level or context-level validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default implementation for validation because it very much depends on your application and business logic.

If you are importing data, it is best to gather all of the unique IDs and then perform a single fetch to determine existence.

If you are creating a new record then I recommend doing the one off, expensive, fetch to determine uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Marcus! So in essence I should forego validation in this case and instead rely on my data generating code to be correct/validate itself? The argument that the code creating the Entities should work correctly in the first place could be made for any validation, so what's the point of having validation at all?

Comment: (Of course I understand there is no default validation implementation - how could there be? What I meant was I see no validation _mechanism_ with a larger scope than one entity instance)

Comment: Validation existed for desktop applications when the UI was wired directly to the model and the UI knew how to reject bad data.  That validation code is not appropriate for the UI on iOS.  The UI on iOS does not have bindings and therefore does not have that capability.